# How to capture POST data with contact form7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have this hook in my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'myfunction' );
```

I want to post the values when the form is sent.

I have a field like this: `[textarea your-message]`.

How do i capture the POST data from this?

for example when the form is sent i want to echo the post value of  `[textarea your-message]` in `myfunction(){}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the `$WPCF7_ContactForm` object.

In your hooked function, you'd access the field you want like this:

```
yourFunction(&$WPCF7_ContactForm) {
    $text_area_contents = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['your-message'];
}
```

Answer (score 14):

This is how I used and its work for me to receive contact form 7 data after successe mail send and I used this data to send another server through API

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function' ); 
function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function( $contact_form ) {
    $title = $contact_form->title;
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();  
    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    }       
   if ( 'Reagistation' == $title ) {
        $name = strtolower($posted_data['text-name']);
        $name = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_',  $name));
        $email = strtolower($posted_data['email']);
        $phone = strtolower($posted_data['phone']);
        $Areyouarealtor = $posted_data['Areyouarealtor'];
        $ayor = strtolower($Areyouarealtor['0']);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_sent', 'your_wpcf7_function' ); 

function your_wpcf7_function( $contact_form ) {
$title = $contact_form->title;
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $submission ) {
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
}
   if ( 'MyContactForm' == $title ) {

    $firstName = $posted_data['first-name'];
    $lastName = $posted_data['last-name'];


   }
}
```

Comment: Or you can just hook into init and retrieve post data.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve form fields data through **wpcf7_posted_data**

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', function( $data ) {
  $name = $data['your-name'];
  // Do something with $name variable.
  return $data;
} );
```

Comment: Definitely the simplest although there's no way to differentiate which form it's handling. Also, need to add `return $data;` or it will break.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

---

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','dynamic_addcc');
function dynamic_addcc($WPCF7_ContactForm){
    $currentformInstance  = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $contactformsubmition = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if($contactformsubmition){
    $posted_data = $contactformsubmition->get_posted_data(); 
    }
}
```